# Issue with Intellij 13.1 when working with a project (java + scala) with multiple source folder

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project (java + scala) which has multiple source folders. 
When I exclude all source folders except one, intelliJ resolves java references properly.
But when I include other source folders, somehow intelliJ resolves only java references in the first occuring source folder only.

Am I missing something here ?

Can someone please help me with this ?

Thanks
Ganesh

Comment: And to be more precise, java references in scala files are only failing.

Comment: Why don't you start with upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 14 and the latest version of the Scala plugin?